# using htaccess to redirect blog post urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

several months ago I changed my permalinks to remove the date.

from
https://jambarteambuilding.com/2014/01/30/maslows-hierarchy-needs/

to
https://jambarteambuilding.com/maslows-hierarchy-needs/

I need to create a redirect in my .htaccess file ensure all the old links with the dates redirect to the new links without the dates.

This webpage discusses how to do an htaccess redirect
https://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-url-permalink/

```
RedirectMatch 301 /d{4}/d{2}/d{2}/(.*) https://jambarteambuilding.com/$1
```

I tried this in the htaccess file in the subdirectory 'clean' above #begin Wordpress.

```
# Redirection of old posts
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 /d{4}/d{2}/d{2}/(.*)
https://jambarteambuilding.com/$1
</IfModule>
# End of Redirection of old posts
```

it broke the website...so I removed it again.

I have my Wordpress install in a subdirectory called 'clean'.

Therefore I have 2 htaccess files.

this one in public_html

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^jambarteambuilding.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://jambarteambuilding.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?jambarteambuilding.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clean/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clean/$1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?jambarteambuilding.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ clean/index.php [L]
```

This one in the subdirectory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
AddHandler application/php-56 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

to be honest im not sure where to go from here. any help would be much appreciated.  I have 954 links to redirect.

Comment: @Jonathan M. Hethe, can you help with this, I just read your article https://jonathanmh.com/wordpress-htaccess-permalink-cheat-sheet/ and it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in the htaccess file in your WordPress directory. I think there is no need to write anything in your first htaccess file you have already done as per [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ https://jambarteambuilding.com/$3
```

reference link [click here](https://brianhogg.com/how-to-change-the-wordpress-permalink-structure-to-remove-dates-from-the-url/)